# countdown timer for virtuemart product

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Please help....

how can we add countdown timer for any product in virtuemart? and is there any way by which we can have total number of products sold with the product display?

Thanks a lot for so much help till now...

And thanks in advance for this one...

Comment: What is the countdown based on? Do you need to set the end time in the admin? VM tracks product sales in the products table so displaying that should be pretty simple.

Comment: the countdown is based on product expiry date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no counter plugin of module available out there to count the total product sold at present. If you want to put the counter in the product page then have to update code in VM component files. If you need I will tell the idea of how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Try this one - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-coupons/16956
It does single product and also categories timers.